# How to reverse an array in Irvine Assembly Language?

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am writing a number manipulation program, and one step is to reverse the array. So far I have

```
reverseArray proc
mov eax, arraySize
mov temp, eax
Imul eax, 4
mov esi, eax
mov eax, 0
mov number, 0
jne L1
L1: 
cmp temp, 0
je L3

mov eax, numbers[esi]
mov tempnumbers[ecx], eax

mov eax, tempnumbers[ecx]
call writeDec
call crlf


sub esi,4
add ecx, 4
sub temp, 1

loop L1


L2:
ret


L3:

.If(number >= 0)

 mov esi, 0
.ENDIF
mov eax, number
cmp eax, arraySize
je L2


mov eax, tempnumbers[esi]
mov numbers[esi], eax

add esi, 4
add number, 1
loop L3
```

However this only reverses about half of my array. Did I do something wrong with the esi or ecx counters? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not clear how you are using `ecx`. Where is it initialized? Why do you `add ecx, 4` and then `loop`? Think this through again, from the top. It may help to write the comments first.

Comment: My thought process was that ecx started at 0 and assigned the place in the temp array with the numbers array final spot. Right before the loop ecx would move ahead one spot and esi would move down one spot. But for some reason it only works for the first five places and then starts to give me large, unrelated numbers

Comment: Probably true that ecx starts at 0 - but I wouldn't count on it! The `loop` instruction decrements ecx, so you're only moving by "three quarters of a spot". I don't know if that's your problem or not...

Answer (score 0):

Use edi instead of ecx, and set it to 0 at the start.